# Streaming audio using libspotifydotnet (Spotify - libspotify)

Tags: c#, spotify, libspotify

After checking out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11452236/how-to-play-a-spotify-music-stream), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6732465/playing-streamed-audio-data-c?rq=1), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13223372/libspotify-playing-problems) post, I understand that I have to `stream` audio using something like `NAudio` and also that playing a song is done by:

```
libspotify.sp_session_player_load(_sessionPtr, trackPtr);
libspotify.sp_session_player_play(_sessionPtr, true);
```

Now, if I understood correctly, I am receiving the `stream` as raw PCM data. How can I access that data?

According to the documentation, I see that that I have to populate `libspotify.sp_audioformat`

How do I do this exactly? and from where?

I was checking out [this](https://spotifyforjamcast.codeplex.com/) project (Jamcast), and they do something like:

```
libspotify.sp_audioformat format = (libspotify.sp_audioformat)Marshal.PtrToStructure(formatPtr, typeof(libspotify.sp_audioformat));
```

Could someone point me in the right direction?
I am completely lost on how to retrieve the `stream`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end, I followed [this](http://forum.openhome.org/archive/index.php?thread-1202.html), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21307520/playing-ohlibspotify-pcm-data-stream-in-c-sharp-with-naudio) question. They helped me out a lot.

I had to do something like this:

```
public static libspotify.sp_error LoadPlayer(IntPtr trackPtr)
{
    bufferedWaveProvider = new BufferedWaveProvider(new WaveFormat());
    bufferedWaveProvider.BufferDuration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(120);

    return libspotify.sp_session_player_load(_sessionPtr, trackPtr);
}

public static void Play()
{
    libspotify.sp_session_player_play(_sessionPtr, true);

    IWavePlayer waveOutDevice = new WaveOut();
    waveOutDevice.Init(bufferedWaveProvider);
    waveOutDevice.Play();
    while (waveOutDevice.PlaybackState == PlaybackState.Playing)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(100);
    }   
}

private static int music_delivery(IntPtr sessionPtr, IntPtr formatPtr, IntPtr framesPtr, int num_frame)
{
    if (num_frame == 0)
        return 0;

    libspotify.sp_audioformat format = (libspotify.sp_audioformat)Marshal.PtrToStructure(formatPtr, typeof(libspotify.sp_audioformat));
    byte[] buffer = new byte[num_frame * sizeof(Int16) * format.channels];
    Marshal.Copy(framesPtr, buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

    bufferedWaveProvider.AddSamples(buffer, 0, num_frame * sizeof(Int16) * format.channels);

    if (Session.OnAudioDataArrived != null)            
        Session.OnAudioDataArrived(buffer);

    return num_frame;

}
```